# One Button, Show/Hide Multiple Divs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am still new to jquery, and am trying to do this: With a click on a button, hide/show informations in the left and right column. I currently have 3 buttons, each showing different information when clicked. And I want it such that when the web page load, the information on the first button will be displayed.

However, currently, both my buttons and information are not working. Any help is appreciated.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xYqX7/18/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="left-container">
    <ul id="illis">
        <li id="more">
            <figure class="idea-image-wrapper"></figure>
            <video width="100%" height="auto" id="myvideo1">
                <source src="videos/all.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
            </video>
        </li>
        <li id="distance">
            <figure class="idea-image-wrapper"></figure>
            <video width="100%" height="auto" id="myvideo2">
                <source src="videos/all_test.mp4" type="skype/mp4" />
            </video>
        </li>
        <li id="art">
            <figure class="idea-image-wrapper"></figure>
            <video width="100%" height="auto" id="myvideo3">
                <source src="videos/all_test.mp4" type="painting/mp4" />
            </video>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <header class="col-3-1">
         <h1 class="title"><b>Kitchen Act</b></h1>

        <ul class="text-items">
            <li id="text-more">
                 <h2>More the merrier.</h2>

                <div class="">
                    <p>Trust me, two brains are better than one.</p>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li id="text-distance">
                 <h2>Distance is not a problem.</h2>

                <div class="">
                    <p>Trust me, two brains are better than one.</p>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li id="text-art">
                 <h2>Eating is art.</h2>

                <div class="">
                    <p>The act of eating encourages the act of creating (cooking, baking are both art generating forms).</p>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="navigation">
            <li class="slidenav content-close active"><a href="#text-more"></a>More</li>
            <li class="slidenav content-close"><a href="#text-distance"></a>Distance</li>
            <li class="slidenav content-close"><a href="#text-art"></a>Art</li>
        </ul>
    </header>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
/*LEFT CONTAINER*/

.left-container{
    position:relative;
    width:67%;
    float:left;
}

#illis{
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    float:right;
    clear:right;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;

    padding-top: 10%;
}

/*
RIGHT CONTAINER*/

#text-distance, #text-art{
    display:none;
}

#content{
    color:#666;
    background-color:#ebebe8;
    position:fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:67%;
    width:100%;
    padding-right:4em;
    z-index: 3;
}

header{
    color:#fff;
    background-color: blue;
}

.col-3-1{
    width:33%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    padding:3em 0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

.col-3-1:first-child{
    padding: 3em 2em;
}

.text-items{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style:none;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var tabs = $('ul#navigation li a');

    tabs.bind('click', function (event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        var ids = tabs.each(function () {
            $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
        });
        $($anchor.attr('href')).fadeIn('slow');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following line at the end of your DOM ready

```
tabs.first().click();
```

And your text should be inside the a elements so that they are clickable.

So that you have:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var tabs = $('ul#navigation li a');

    tabs.bind('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $anchor = $(this);
        var otherShow = '#' + this.href.split('-')[1];
        tabs.each(function () {
            var other = '#' + this.href.split('-')[1];
            $( other ).hide();
            $( $(this).attr('href') ).hide();
        });
        $( $anchor.attr('href') ).fadeIn('slow');
        $( otherShow ).fadeIn('slow');
    });

    tabs.first().click();
});

<a href="#...">Text to be clicked</a>
```

[JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/YKbpL/1/show/)

Comment: hi thank you for this, but same problem as the suggestion given below: the information in the right column changes with the button click, however, the information in the left column, does not. How can I do it such that, when user click button "More", div #text-more and #more is displayed. And same applies to the other divs

Comment: What is one supposed to see on the left? I have updated the code and the left page is changing too. The demo is updated too.

Comment: on the left, it is supposed to be videos. So when u click button "More", left shows video, right shows infomration

Comment: Try the updated code on your site since you have the videos. Let me know if there's any problem.

Comment: hi, sorry another question. Is it possible to have the videos to be on autoplay once button is clicked? I tried autoplay, but the moment the page load, everything plays.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54006/discussion-between-user3558931-and-user3453264).

Answer (score 2):

First, put the nav text inside the `<a>` tags.

```
  <ul id="navigation">
     <li class="slidenav content-close active"><a href="#text-more">More</a></li>
     <li class="slidenav content-close"><a href="#text-distance">Distance</a></li>
     <li class="slidenav content-close"><a href="#text-art">Art</a></li>
  </ul>
```

using this `css`, hide all the videos initially:

```
#illis li{
    display: none;
}
```

and, I've made some revisions on your jQuery:

**UPDATE: Added script so the video will play automatically when the respective tab is clicked**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var tabs = $('#navigation li a');
     $("#more").fadeIn("slow");              // show default video
     $('#myvideo1').get(0).play();           // play default video
    tabs.click(function () {
       var $anchor = $(this).attr("href");
       tabs.each(function(){  
       var $curr = $(this).attr("href");
           $($curr).hide();
                });
        if($anchor == "#text-distance"){
            $("#more").hide();
            $("#art").hide();  
            $("#distance").fadeIn("slow");
            $('#myvideo2').get(0).play();   // play respective video
            $('#myvideo1').get(0).pause();  // pause the other videos
            $('#myvideo3').get(0).pause();  // pause the other videos
        }
        if($anchor == "#text-more"){
            $("#more").fadeIn("slow");
            $("#art").hide();  
            $("#distance").hide();
            $('#myvideo1').get(0).play();
            $('#myvideo2').get(0).pause();
            $('#myvideo3').get(0).pause();
        }
        if($anchor == "#text-art"){
            $("#more").hide();
            $("#art").fadeIn("slow");  
            $("#distance").hide();
            $('#myvideo3').get(0).play();
            $('#myvideo1').get(0).pause();
            $('#myvideo2').get(0).pause();
        }
        $($anchor).fadeIn("slow");
        event.preventDefault();
    });


});
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xYqX7/21/)** `//Used sample videos just for demo`

Comment: Hi, thank you for this. The information in the right column changes with the button click, however, the information in the left column, does not. 

How can I do it such that, when user click button "More", div #text-more and #more is displayed. And same applies to the other divs

Comment: Oh ok, I'll look into it.